# Distributing tasks over HTTP using SpringBoot non-blocking WebClient (performance question?)

Tags: concurrency, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have a large number of tasks - N, needs to be distributed to multiple http worker nodes via load balancer. Though there exists multiple nodes  - n, combining all nodes we have a max-concurrency setting - x.

```
Always
N > x > n
```

One node can run those tasks in multiple threads. Mean time consumption for each task is about 50 sec to 1 min. Using Web-Client to distribute tasks and Mono response from Workers.

There exists a distributor and designed the process as follows:

```
 1. Remove a task from queue.
 2. Send the task via POST request using Web-Client and subscribe immediately with a subscriber instance
 3. Holt new subscription when max concurrency reached to x
 4. When any one of the above distributed task completes it calls on-accept(T) method of the subscriber.
 5. If task queue is not empty, remove and send the next task / (x+1) task.
 6. Keep track of total number completed tasks.
 7. If all tasks completed & queue empty set Completable Future object as complete
 8. Exit
```

The above process works fine. Tested with N=5000, n=10 & x=25.

Now the confusion is in this design we always have x number of concurrent subscriptions. As soon as one ends we create another until all tasks are completed. What is the impact of this in large scale production environment? If number of concurrent subscription (the value of x > 10,000) increases via the HTTP(s) load balancer is that going to have serious impact on performance and network latency? Our expected production volume will be something like below:

```
N=200,000,000
n=100
x=10,000
```

I will be grateful if some one with knowledge of Reactor and Web-Client expertise comment of this approach. Our main concern is having too many concurrent subscriptions.

Comment: Concurrent subscriptions aren't an issue - reactor is designed to easily allow tens of thousands of these. That being said, are the tasks here IO heavy or CPU (computationally) heavy? If they're just heavy in terms of IO (making lots of network requests, doing minimal processing) then that's fine. If it's computationally heavy reactor likely isn't going to be the best fit, and your limit is almost certainly going to be with available CPU resource. That being said, best by far is to benchmark your actual scenario and then observe performance.

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelBerry. Yes I was expecting the same answer. Our reactor distributor is very light weight. It does hardly any processing. Just pickup a task from the queue, make a decision whether to proceed or not, POST a simple java Object, subscribe and receives a simple POJO with task status and message.

Comment: To add -  handling the issue that the task-distributor could be a single point of failure we are planning to have multiple instance of distributor (either stand by or round-robin) to handle fail over. Will do bench marking and post the result. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, that all sounds like a sensible approach to me.